# Having trouble setting up the escrow function - returns transaction ID but doesn't get to blockchain?

Tags: multi-signature, escrow

Looking at both this example:
https://earlytemple.com:8181/index.jsp
and this example:
https://gist.github.com/gavinandresen/3966071

I think I plowed through everything to the point where I was doing it all right: I made sure the transaction funding the escrow account came from one of the two parties in the multisig address, in this case it was

createmultisig 2 '["02bf4782452f7605994a27ad130ff2d6ee7f2e3399f8c0be79a114a5c116794277","035602e50d80b4c0066d4bb004f33557b100d421f02a32cd853bb24ead7bbfd351"]'
which produced the escrow address 3QQTMoaJZzkRqWAavPJRvEcTTFt7sRxiPL.

I funded the transaction manually with createrawtransaction, pulling from one of these two accounts, then I created a redemption transaction, then I signed that the way specified in the instructions, then I went to the other machine running bitcoin-qt and signed the output of the previous signing operation with the private key on that side, then I tried a send operation from that machine (didn't let me) so I went back to the original machine and sent it from there (did let me) and it returned a transaction ID of 30a6693a74e9c60a34af0262c14e516dd4ffa75cb9f496cd2f6ba484135bbe2a, which does not seem to be getting into the blockchain.  I've had that happen about three times now.  I specified settxfee 0.0002 to make sure (I hoped) that I was paying to get it included?

Can anybody point me in the right direction here?  I really could get a lot of use out of this function if I could get it to work, and I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Struggled with this for a while as well. You need to announce the transaction to your local node and the network via the [`sendrawtransaction`](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Raw_Transactions#sendrawtransaction_.3Chex_string.3E) call with the raw transaction id.